# Spring-boot liquibase integration

Tags: spring, liquibase, spring-boot

Although I raised issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/662 to provide a spring-boot-starter-liquibase-starter module, today I found out that there is already some kind of integration.

Spring Boot already contains https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/liquibase with a Spring Boot Liquibase specific service locator.
From this code and the Spring Boot reference guide I cannot figure out what Spring Boot is already offering.

However I also found out that when adding Gradle dependency "org.liquibase:liquibase-core" (note without version number) it automatically resolves liquibase 3.1.1 so the Spring Boot specific dependency resolver is doing some 'magic' here.

Anyone knows what kind of integration Spring Boot is offering in terms of Liquibase?
I would like to automatically perform migrations (if needed) during startup of the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot knows about Liquibase and detects it on the classpath (hence the magic dependency resolution). Liquibase has an SPI for creating its services that we implement in a special way so they work with the executable JAR format that Spring Boot supports. So, in short, if it's there and you add it to your context it will work (as mentioned briefly [in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool)). But there is no "autoconfiguration" out of the box (we can use your github issue to manage that if you want a new feature).

Comment: Thanks for explanation Dave. Currently Spring Boot is nothing special to run automatically to run migrations. Let's discuss feature request further in mentioned guthub issue.

Comment: I have read you're discussions (and the docs )but I have one problem, i have set liquibase-core as a dependency in the class path, I have assigned a path to a file in the resource properties to the liquibase.change-log variable, but when i run my springboot application nothing change inside the database, how could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

For more information about how we can integrate liquibase with Spring Boot, you can check the tutorial [integrate liquibase](https://codezup.com/integrate-liquibase-with-spring-boot-application/).